# How to use more than one _base.html file using django-two-factor-auth?

Tags: python, django, django-two-factor-auth

Django-two-factor-auth library requires a _base.html file to customize the styling for integration.

I need the base for my login page to be different to that of the other two factor pages. How can I use two different _base.html files instead of using the same _base.html for all the two factor urls?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Solved! Just posted how I worked around it. Don't know why Django-two-factor would assume the base styling of the login page and settings/setup page should be the same ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your project directory, add a folder called `templates`, same level as your apps such as `users`, `blogs`, etc. Inside of it, create another folder for `two_factor`. Inside of this folder, put your modified `base.html`.

If somehow you get error message, in your `settings.py` under `TEMPLATES = [`. Replace

```
'DIRS': [],
```

with

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # in django2
```

or

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR.joinpath('templates')],# in django3
```

Here is [Doc about templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration)

**Update after op's own answer**

If you want to have `two_factor/templates/two_factor/core/login.html` use your own `base.html`, you should follow what I mentioned above, you will have `templates/two_factor/core/login.html`. Note that `templates` is in the same directory level as your other `apps`. In the `templates` folder, generate `two_factor` folder, then inside of it, generate `core` folder, then inside of that generate `login.html`. You can now modify it whichever you want to.

The reason that you want to override but not change things in the package directory is because when you update your package you have to make the changes again manually.

The reason that the approach above works is since we put `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]` in settings, Django will look for this folder first for templates. The detailed application of this method is here [Overriding from the project’s templates directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-the-project-s-templates-directory)

Comment: I am trying to configure two base files. One for the login route and another for the other Two factor routes

Comment: Your solution works but not ideal. I updated my answer, the approach i mentioned is exactly for this kind of situation.

Comment: Just read the updated answer. Very good point about maintainability! Updated my code/folders and everything works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by manually changing the following line in the package directory `two_factor/templates/two_factor/core/login.html` referencing the `_base.html` file to the base template of my login page.

```
{% extends "two_factor/_base_focus.html" %}
```

I then continued to use the `_base.html` to customize the other two factor pages.